# Pandas dataframe calculations between rows

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, indexing, timedelta

I'm trying to read a log and compute the duration of a certain workflow. So the dataframe containing the log looks something like this:

```
Timestamp    Workflow    Status
20:31:52     ABC         Started
...
...
20:32:50     ABC         Completed
```

In order to compute the duration, I am doing using the following code:

```
start_time = log_text[(log_text['Workflow']=='ABC') & (log_text['Category']=='Started')]['Timestamp']
compl_time = log_text[(log_text['Workflow']=='ABC') & (log_text['Category']=='Completed')]['Timestamp']
duration = compl_time - start_time
```

and the answer I get is:

```
1    NaT
72   NaT
Name: Timestamp, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

I think since the index is different, the time difference is not being calculated correctly. Of course, I could get the correct answer by using the index of each row explicitly by:

`duration = compl_time.loc[72] - start_time[1]`

But this seems to be an inelegant way of doing things. Is there a better way to accomplish the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, there is problem with different `indexes`, so output cannot be aligned and get `NaN`s.

The simpliest is convert output to `numpy array` by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html), but need same lenght of both `Series` (here both are `length == 1`), for selecting with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) is better use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
mask = log_text['Workflow']=='ABC'
start_time = log_text.loc[mask & (log_text['Status']=='Started'), 'Timestamp']
compl_time = log_text.loc[mask & (log_text['Status']=='Completed'),'Timestamp']

print (len(start_time))
1
print (len(compl_time))
1

duration = compl_time - start_time.values

print (duration)
1   00:00:58
Name: Timestamp, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

---

```
duration = compl_time.values - start_time.values

print (pd.to_timedelta(duration))
TimedeltaIndex(['00:00:58'], dtype='timedelta64[ns]', freq=None)

print (pd.Series(pd.to_timedelta(duration)))
0   00:00:58
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```